# Is there apt-cacher for Windows?

Tags: apt, repository

I have two computers.

- C1: Windows with Internet connection.
- C2: Ubuntu connected with C1 but not connected with Internet.

I'd like to access apt repositories to update or install some packages on Ubuntu.

I heard, apt-cacher is one of solutions, but I couldn't find apt-cacher for Windows (It is only one, I have, with Internet connection).

Please let me know how to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no apt-cacher for windows, although you could just as easily proxy the internet connection from the windows machine to your ubuntu machine. This assumes you have admin access to the windows machine... wich you would have needed for an apt-cacher service install anyway.

Your other option is to do an apt mirror, this involves downloading the entire ubuntu archive onto your local computer (about 3GB) which you can host from windows via apache. You can then point your Ubuntu machine at it.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `apt-offline` or `apt-offline-gui`.
**Pre-requistes**: A friend's system with Internet connection. apt-offline installed in both your systems.

The Offline installation is achieved in 3 simple steps.

**Step 1**:
Generate a signature file on the Disconnected Debian box at home
`apt-offline set /tmp/apt-offline.sig`
The above command will generate all information required from apt about updating its database.

**Step 2**:
Download data based on the signature file generated earlier
`apt-offline get C:\apt-offline.sig --threads 5`
The above command will download data as mentioned in the signature file. To speed up downloads (that can be from multiple apt repositories), in this example we spawn 5 download threads.
Once completed, you could just copy the data (an archive file, if you used the --bundle option) back to the removable medium and copy it back onto your offline host.

**Step 3**:
Once you're back upon the home Debian machine, you feed the data from the removable medium to apt-offline:
`apt-offline install /media/USB/apt-offline.zip`
This will update the APT database on your disconnected machine seamlessly.

**Apt-offline can be even be used in Windows systems**. In my opinion, `apt-offline` is the best option for Offline installation.

[Source](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT)

Answer (score 0):

You can either setup a proxy on windows (probably http://serverfault.com has some suggestions) or, if you don't mind the resource usage, install [andLinux](http://andlinux.org/) to have ubuntu run as a background process on your windows installation and use the usual ubuntu apt-caching

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to try Keryx which will allow you to manage packages on your offline Ubuntu computer using your online Windows computer's internet connection and a flash drive. Keyrx provides a Windows package as well as a Debian package.

http://keryxproject.org/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!

I solved my problem installing VirtualBox on Windows.

Then I installed Ubuntu on VirtualBox.
(Some additional configuration needed like port forwarding)

Eventually, I could use apt-cacher on this Ubuntu system.

Ted